# Filtering non prime numbers out of a stream in Scheme

Tags: filter, stream, scheme, racket

I am trying to define a function in scheme that filters a stream of numbers. My function will take in a number num and a stream s and filter out where the num is a factor of a number in the stream.

My code currently looks like this:

```
(define filter$
  (lambda (num s)
    (if (or (= num 0)(null? s))
        '()
        (if (= (modulo (car s) num) 0)
            (filter$ num (cdr s))
            (cons (car s) (filter$ num (cdr s)))))))
```

I am currently receiving an error:

```
car: contract violation
expected: pair?
given: #<procedure:... saved location of file/location of the error>
```

I'm working in Racket for this(specifically DrRacket) and it is school work. I'm hoping to receive help in understanding what is causing this error and what I can do to fix it.

Comment: What arguments are you passing to `filter$` that produces this error?

Answer (score 2):

A stream is not the same as a list. You cannot just use `car` since `car` only works on pairs.

Even though you wrote that you are using DrRacket I have no idea what language you are working in. Often it's learning languages, but in this answer I assume it's either Racket's default language or a proper Scheme report language.

In the `#!racket` language, the equivalent to `first` (or `car`) for streams is `stream-first`. For the rest of the prodcedures and special forms [see the documentation.](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/streams.html)

For Scheme languages (like `#!r6rs` or `#!r5rs`) you can use [SRFI-40](http://docs.racket-lang.org/srfi/srfi-std/srfi-40.html). Here it's `stream-car`, which is used instead of `stream-first`, so the Scheme and Racket languages are not compatible on this point.